Cost function for time series anomaly detection with limited labelled anomalies
Given a time series $y_1, \dots, y_n$, I will fit some models to the data and I want to choose one for anomaly identification. I'm interested in a cost function that rewards a model whose fitted values $\hat{y}_t$ closely match $y_t$ most of the time, but the residuals $y_t - \hat{y}_t$ are large when $y_t$ is anomalous. I'm interested in the residual rather than a binary indicator of whether it's an anomaly for my application. Anomalies in my application are individual points that differ greatly from expected, so if a time series was gradually increasing and then changed to be gradually decreasing there would not be an anomaly there.
I don't have labeled anomalies, but the time series I'm looking at represent daily data, and I know that public holidays generally coincide with anomalous behavior. So I'm thinking that the cost function should have the form along the following lines, where $H$ is the set of holidays,
$$C_1\left(\left\{y_t - \hat{y}_t : t \in H \right\}\right) + \lambda C_2\left(\left\{y_t - \hat{y}_t : t \notin H \right\}\right).$$
I'm considering setting $C_1$ to be the median absolute deviation (MAD), a robust estimator of the variance of the residuals because there are surely some anomalies that are not included in the holidays. Using the MAD means that I will estimate the fit on just the regular data.
$$C_1\left(r\right) = \textrm{MAD}\left(\{r_1, \dots\} \right) = 1.48 \times \textrm{median}\left(\left|r_t - \textrm{median}(r_t)\right|\right).$$
And $C_2$ could be something like
$$C_2(r) = -Var(r) = -\frac{\sum r_t^2}{|r|}$$
to reward the model for not overfitting. And $\lambda$ would be chosen to balance these two (maybe set to $1$).
Are there any issues with using this approach? You might be wondering why I'm not using cross-validation. I don't consider anomaly detection in this case to be a forecasting task - I have an observation for each day, and I want to determine which do not match the behavior of the surrounding points. Plus one of the models I have to use due to the codebase that I'm building on, Python's statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STl, doesn't handle missing values well (there is a future-forecasting version of the function but forecasting using only past data is an unnecessary constraint). And why not an information criterion? I don't have a good way of estimating the number of parameters in the models and they are quite structurally different. It would be good to include a penalty for model complexity, but I'm not sure how it would work.
The models that I'm considering are STL, a dual-lowess model where I fit one lowess model for the weekdays and one for weekends (for when the behaviour on each weekday is basically the same), and just lowess. Each of the models should be applicable to some of the time series that I'm looking at. To be clear, for each time series my plan is to fit all three models on it and use the model with the lowest cost.
